# Lorentz transformation of a frequency modulated signal

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

**Let's consider the following problem:**

A spacecraft starts at time $t_0 = 0$ with speed $v > 0$ and moves along the $x$-axis. If the distance between spacecraft and earth equals $R$ (in the reference frame of the earth), i.e. at $t=\frac{R}{v}$ a frequency modulatated signal

$$
u \colon \left[ \frac{R}{v}, \frac{R}{v} + \tau \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
u(t) \colon= u_0 \cos\left( F\left(t - \frac{R}{v}\right) \right)
$$

of duration $\tau$ is sent from earth to the spacecraft. To compute the signal received from the spacecraft we have to consider the spacetime-signal

$$
u(t, x) = u_0 \cos\left( F\left(t - \frac{R}{v} - \frac{x}{c}\right) \right)
$$

and use the Lorentz transformation, i.e.,

$$
t^\prime = \gamma \left( t + \frac{vx}{c^2} \right)\\
x^\prime = \gamma \left( x + vt \right).
$$

Hence, we get the transformation

$$
\left(t - \frac{x}{c}\right) \longrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{c-v}{c+v}} \left(t - \frac{x}{c}\right),
$$

and clearly see the Doppler shift.

**Let's come to the actual question:**

Assume that the spacecraft did not start at $t_0=0$ from earth. Instead an observer from earth knows that the distance to the spacecraft at $t_0=0$ is $R$ and that it moves with $v\geqslant 0$.

**Question 1:** What is the correct Lorentz transform in that case? For example we could just shift the time, i.e.,

$$
t^\prime = \gamma \left( t + \frac{R}{v} + \frac{vx}{c^2} \right)\\
x^\prime = \gamma \left( x + R + vt \right),
$$

but obviously the limiting case $v \to 0$ does not exist.

**Question 2:** A spatial shift instead of a time shift, i.e.,
$$
t^\prime = \gamma \left( t + \frac{v(x+R)}{c^2} \right)\\
x^\prime = \gamma \left( x + R + vt \right),
$$

is somewhat confusing for me. At least the limiting case $v \to 0$ exists in this case, but what is the inverse of this transformation if the spacecraft also knows that the distance to earth at $t_0 = 0$ is $R$ (in the reference frame of the earth). Probably I have a wrong understanding about simultaneity and synchronization of both reference frames...

Maybe someone can shed light on the darkness :)

Comment: Are you asking about the Lorentz transformation of frequency?  If so, just look up relativistic Doppler effect (radio waves always move at the speed of light in space).

Comment: Hi honeste_vivere, am asking for the correct way to compute the signal $u$ in the moving frame of the spacecraft, i.e., the signal received by the spacecraft, in case the two frames do not align at $t_0=0$.

Comment: As I suggested, the signal should move at the speed of light no matter what, which means that the spacecraft speed is negligible in almost all cases (i.e., for delay time unless you care about micro- to nanoseconds).  The thing that will measurably change based upon spacecraft-to-source speed is the frequency of the received signal by either the source or the spacecraft (e.g., the frequency received at the source will be different than that emitted by the spacecraft).

Comment: Just to be clear, the signal propagates at the speed of light no matter which direction the spacecraft moves with respect to the receiver.  So moving toward the receiver won't make the signal reach it faster than the speed of light just as moving away won't delay the signal arrival time.  The speed of light is constant and invariant in a vacuum.

Comment: Of course, the speed of the spacecraft is negligible (compared to the constant ;) speed of light), but I want to do an exact calculation of the received signal. Since it is a frequency modulated signal, it's not just about a single Doppler shift. Instead I want to compute the exact phase of the signal with a Lorentz transform.

Comment: Well $\phi = \omega \ t - \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{x} = \omega' \ t' - \mathbf{k}' \cdot \mathbf{x}'$, i.e., phase is a Lorentz invariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the correct Lorentz transform in that case?

There is no need to change the Lorentz transform at all in that case. It is perfectly fine for a ship to be located somewhere other than the origin. In fact, even in the original scenario although the ship starts at the origin by the time it finishes the signal it is no longer at the origin. That is not important in either scenario.

However, if you want to transform it then there is no problem doing a spatial and/or temporal translation. The order of operations matters, it is different to do a translation first followed by a boost vs a boost followed by a translation. Based on the description, I think that a translation followed by a boost makes more sense. The overall combined transform would be: $$ t'= \gamma \left( t+ \Delta t +\frac{v \ (x+\Delta x)}{c^2} \right)$$ $$x' = \gamma \left( x+ \Delta x + v \ (t+\Delta t) \right)$$

For your scenario as I understand it $\Delta x = R$ and $\Delta t = 0$ so the above simplifies to $$ t'= \gamma \left( t +\frac{v \ (x+R)}{c^2} \right)$$ $$x' = \gamma \left( x+ R + v \ t \right)$$ Note that this agrees with your second expression.

Now, your first expression is a little odd. What you are doing is shifting in time, but you are shifting in time by the time that it takes for the ship to arrive at the origin traveling a distance of $R$ at a speed $v$. If $v=0$ then there is no such time. This has nothing to do with relativity, the same thing would happen in Newtonian physics. If $v=0$ then the ship stays at $R$ and never arrives at Earth.

> what is the inverse of this transformation

The inverse transform is found simply by algebraically solving the forward transform listed above: $$t=\gamma \left( t' - \frac{v \ x'}{c^2} \right) - \Delta t$$ $$x = \gamma \left( x'- v \ t' \right) -\Delta x $$ Note that this is not simply the first transformation listed with the signs reversed.

That is because the order of transformations matters. A translation followed by a boost is different from a boost followed by a translation. And the inverse of a translation followed by a boost is not a translation followed by a boost. In fact, the inverse of a translation followed by a boost is a boost followed by a translation. That is the form that we see in the final expression.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. There is just one think which somewhat confuses me: How to apply the principle of relativity in that case and what is the inverse transform? If I change $v \leftrightarrow -v$ and $R \leftrightarrow -R$ (the later is probably wrong) it is not an inverse of the first transform...

Comment: @Bananarama oops, you are right. You asked about that in your question and I missed it. Give me a few minutes and I will update the answer with that information

Comment: @Bananarama done!

Comment: Well done... Thank you, Dale! There is just one thing left: Of course, one can get the inverse by algebraically solving the equations, but how to derive the inverse transformation from the passengers perspective? Why does he not come to the same result as the one on earth? I am just missing the "symmetry"... Can you explain that a little further?

Comment: @Bananarama well, that is difficult because it is not symmetric. The $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ are given in one frame. That frame is then identifiable in the equations.

Comment: In this case, it is necessary to take the inhomogeneous transformations of Lorentz or transformation of Poincaré.                                                                                               https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoincareTransformation.html